# I have recreated a query with four fields, how can i sum all the F1 to F4 in the query?

Tags: ms-access

[image]
i try to add but it returns blank as in field [Expr1]

Answer (score 0):

Use *Nz* to add 0 (zero) for empty fields:

```
Expr1: Nz([F1],0)+Nz([F2],0)+Nz([F3],0)+Nz([F4],0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Nz function to return zero, a zero-length string (" "), or another specified value when a Variant is Null. so try:

```
SELECT Nz(F1)+Nz(F2)+Nz(F3)+Nz(F4) AS Expr1
    From [Table1]
```